# unable to pass a variable in POST request in Gatling

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

**In the below code, when I try to pass the bearer_token variable to the header in the POST request execution, the request is getting failed.

But if I pass the value instead of a variable to the header then the request is success. How should I pass the variable to the POST request.**

```
class test extends Simulation{

  val headersLogin = Map(
    "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
    "Authorization" -> "Basic YWRtaW46Tm9raWFOc3AxIQ=="
  )

  val headersCreateSubscription = Map(
    "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
    "Accept" -> "application/json"
  )

  var bearer_token = ""

    val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl("https://135.121.159.176") // Here is the root for all relative URLs

  val scn =
    scenario("Telemetry Viewer Load Testing")
      .exec(
        http("Get Access Token - POST ")
          .post(":443/rest-gateway/rest/api/v1/auth/token")
          .headers(headersLogin)
          .body(StringBody(
            """{"grant_type": "client_credentials" }""".stripMargin)).asJson
          .check(status is 200)
          .check(jsonPath("$" ).saveAs("RESPONSE_DATA" ))
          .check(jsonPath("$.access_token").saveAs("access_token"))
      )
  
      .exec( session => {
        val token = session("access_token").as[String]
        println( s"ACCESS TOKEN - $token")
        bearer_token ="Bearer ".concat(token)
        session
      })
   
    .exec(
      http("CREATE SUBSCRIPTION - POST")
        .post(":8619/telemetry-viewer/api/v1/restconf/data/telemetry-data-subscription:/subscriptions")
//        .header("Authorization", "Bearer VEtOLWFkbWluNDdiOWY2ZDUtNTMyYS00NDJlLWI1MmItZmFmYTFjZTFlZGEz")
//        .headers(headersCreateSubscription)
        .headers(Map(
          "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
          "Authorization" -> s"${bearer_token}",
          "Accept" -> "application/json"
        ))
        .body(StringBody("""{"subscription": [{"name": "ap_11111", "collection-interval": 60, "telemetry": [ { "id": 1,  "type": "telemetry:/base/system-info/system"}]}]}""".stripMargin)).asJson
        .check(status is 201)
        .check(jsonPath("$" ).saveAs("CREATE_SUBSCRIPTION_RESPONSE_DATA" ))
    )

    .exec(session => {
      val response = session("CREATE_SUBSCRIPTION_RESPONSE_DATA").as[String]
      println(s"CREATE SUBSCRIPTION - RESPONSE BODY: \n$response")
      session
    }
    )

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpProtocol))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use global vars/references, they would be shared amongst all virtual users

Remove this exec block that doesn't help and use Gatling EL to resolve directly:

```scala
.header("Authorization", "Bearer ${access_token}")
```